# Store multiple text selections in localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension that allows a user to highlight text on a webpage. Simple, but it's to help me learn. Right now, I'm stuck and looking for how to best solve a problem.

Currently, I can highlight selected text that persists on the page.

**JavaScript**

```
function addHilite(color) {
    var range, sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
        range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    document.designMode = "on";

    if (range) {
        sel.addRange(range);
    };

    if (!document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "#FFFF00")) {
        document.execCommand("backColor", false, "#FFFF00");
    }
    document.designMode = "off";
    console.log(range);
}
```

I'm trying to get to a point where the user could select a highlighted range and use the same browser action to undo a highlight. I thought `localStorage` would be a good way to save the state between each click, but I can't figure out how to store multiple ranges as a string for reference. Is there a better way to do this?

**`localStorage` Experiment**

```
function sel() {
    var getText = window.getSelection().toString();
    localStorage.setItem('getText', JSON.stringify(getText));

    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('getText')));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
var selections = [];

function sel() {
    var getText = window.getSelection().toString();
    selections.push(getText);
    localStorage.setItem('getText', selections);

    console.log(localStorage.getItem('getText'));
}
```

Comment: I see what you're going for, but it produces the same result as my original script. Unless, I'm not calling the array properly to display **all** of the stored data.